# What is the minimum row height Excel allow?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I try to set row height to .01 then unhide a range of rows which includes that row height of .01. The row that i set to .01 is now the same row as the one of top and bottom. So what is the minimum row height allowed on Excel?

I try -1 and I get prompt of must enter 0 to 409.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with the minimum height? The minimum height interacts with the default row height. Select all the cells on a sheet, and change the default font. You can get it to a unusable tiny size as a result.

Comment: @bvaughn what do you mean change the default font? I'm trying to hide away the rows that if a macro or manual unhide of any rows that contains those rows that has been set by .01 doesn't default back the row height on top and bottom rows.

Comment: @pokemon_Man are you trying to hide rows by setting the height, or set to a tiny height *without* hiding?

Comment: @Random832 I want to hide rows by setting it to very tiny. so that if i hide or unhide those rows, it will not show.

Comment: @pokemon_Man Why don't you want to just use "hide" directly? Are you trying to do this in a program or interactively?

Comment: @Random832 Because these rows are withing a amount of rows that i will need to hide and unhide. when i unhide this range of rows, these rows that i set to very tiny defaults back to 15 lets say.

Comment: @pokemon_Man The smallest I can set it to with the mouse is 1 pixel which is 0.75. I think the number is in points

Comment: if i set it to .1, it is fine, if i try .01, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm... the *maximum* height being 409.5 suggests a fixed point format. Try 0.0625.

Comment: no, it defaults back, .1 works but with 20 lines, it creates a thick dark line when print preview which i don't want to show.

Comment: .1 doesn't even work for me - like .68 works and that rounds to .75 when i go back into it. What version of excel are you on? Have you considered using outline mode so that people can unhide the desired rows without unhiding these?

Comment: excel 2007, these hiding and unhiding rows are done by macro lets say clicking a checkbox will unhide nTh amount of rows. seems like the lowest i could go is .08

Comment: If you're using a macro, write your macro to specifically unhide the rows you want instead of unhiding the whole range. If you are recording instead of writing, do it with all the rows you don't want the macro to affect visible while recording the macro, so you can select the separate ranges to hide, then hide them afterwards.

Comment: @Random832 i don't want to have to write code to hide and unhide those rows everytime.

Comment: To echo @bvaughn's comment at the very beginning, *why* do you want to get the rows this small? This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You want to keep some rows hidden from view, but not technically `Rows.Visible = False`? So you're looking for the smallest possible value to do this?

Comment: @pokemon_Man Isn't the point of a macro that you write it once?